# Watir for Wireshark

Tags: automation, watir, wireshark

I have written a Java program using JnetPcap library that reads from an offline Pcap file generated from Wireshark and develop statistics for my data(Web traffic) . But I need a way to automate the whole process of capturing(from different websites),saving the file(after the capture is completed), Running my program. I am a novice to Scripting languages. Can anyone please tell me if Watir helps me accomplishing my task ? Else Please suggest the a scripting language that best suits my requirement.

Thank You

Answer (score 2):

Watir drives browsers. If you need to drive a browser, it can do it.

Comment: Watir + other Ruby tools & libraries can be extremely powerful.  Like Željko said, it can certainly handle the browser parts.  If you don't need to see the browser, the Mechanize or net/http library may have less overhead.

Comment: Also to be clear Watir is not a scripting language.  Watir is a library of ruby based code that makes it easy to drive a browser.  The primary emphasis is on testing webpages and webapps, but people use it for more than that.  Since watir is based on Ruby, if you do not know ruby and do know Java, your might be better off to seek a Java library for doing either HTTP requests, or driving a browser (Perhaps Selenium).  Personally I find watir easier to use than Se, but if I was a Java junkie who did not know ruby I might feel otherwise